# how can i add class or span tag at sprintf?

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic

i hope to add span tag or class at sprintf

I want to enlarge the text size of the numbers in front of me. So I want to add span tag or class only to text in front of me.

my code is

```
            /**
             * Filters the product average rating.
             *
             * @since 1.10.0
             *
             * @param float $average_rating average rating
             * @param \WC_Product $product the product object
             */
            $average_rating = max( 0, (float) apply_filters( 'wc_product_reviews_pro_product_rating_average', $product->get_average_rating(), $product ) );

            $reviews_count  = max( 0, wc_product_reviews_pro_get_contributions_count( $product, 'review' ) );

            /* translators: Placeholders: %s - average rating stars count (float casted as string to avoid trailing zeroes), %d - 5 stars total (integer) -- (e.g "4.2 / 5 stars") */
            $reviews_label  = sprintf( __( '%s / %d', 'woocommerce-product-reviews-pro' ), $average_rating, 5 );

            ?>
            <h3><?php echo esc_html( $reviews_label ); ?></h3>

            <p><?php echo get_star_rating(); ?></p>
```

I tried many ways.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45312511/adding-class-to-element-in-php-code
I've taken a lot of reference to the above url

But all the results are printed like `<span>4</span>/5`.
I don't want it to be  in print.

Is there a good solution?
thanks.

Comment: can you share your actual code?

Comment: @ShirGans 
It's not my code.
I'm not sure if I can share the entire code because it's a code for a paid plug-in template.
Is there no problem sharing?

Comment: No, better not to share the entire code. First you better not change the original plugin code, since it's not a good practice at all. All you changes should be made on your own template (or child template) using hooks and filters. This way your changes will not be erased. 
Anyway, could you share what code gave you the result of <span>4</span>/5 ?

Comment: i tried 

`$reviews_label  =  sprintf( __( '<span>%s</span> / %d', 'woocommerce-product-reviews-pro' ), $average_rating, 5 );`

and 

`$reviews_label  =  <span> . sprintf( __( '%s</span> / %d', 'woocommerce-product-reviews-pro' ), $average_rating, 5 );`

But it doesn't work the way I want it to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actaully using `esc_html` won't help because it will escape any html character, so you have to depend on `wp_kses` so you can specify the accepted tags and there attributes, so no need then to escape the output. but you have to escape the values comming from DB, which in you case `$average_rating`. so your can be like this.

```
$accepted_tags  = array('strong'=>array());

$reviews_label  = wp_kses(
                        sprintf( 
                            __( '%s / %d', '<strong>woocommerce-product-reviews-pro</strong>' ), 
                            esc_html($average_rating), 
                            5 
                        ), 
                    $accepted_tags );

<h3><?php echo $reviews_label ; ?></h3>
```

> Update

As i can see from your comment, You need to add tag to the `%s`, so you need to just change the `$accepted_tags` to:

```
$accepted_tags  = array('span'=>array());
```

anf the `sprintf` to:

```
sprintf( 
        __( '<span>%s</span> / %d', 'woocommerce-product-reviews-pro' ), 
        esc_html($average_rating), 
        5 
    ),
```

Comment: it worked perfectly.
I don't understand what happened.
I've saved a lot of time thanks to you.
And I learned a lot !

Comment: Glad I could help,  you are welcome